# Tag synonym for KnockoutJS

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I don't have enough points to suggest tag synonyms so I post here instead. I browsed through the list of questions tagged [knockout](/questions/tagged/knockout) and they all relate to the Knockout JS library.

Questions tagged with:

- [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) x 1323
- [knockout](/questions/tagged/knockout) x 33
- [knockoutjs2](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs2) x 24

I guess we should merge first two tags (and may be the third tag as well).

Comment: Should the primary tag be "knockout" or "knockout-js"?  Also, how should the version-specific tag look?

Comment: I guess "knockout" is better. It's the official name of the library. Home page at http://knockoutjs.com/ says simply Knockout. GitHub repo is https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout and the docs always uses "Knockout". On the other hand, "knockoutjs" has a lot more questions and is named in similar manner to "underscore.js" and "backbone.js" so may be "knockout.js" (mind the dot) is more suitable.

Comment: It would seem the ".js" is something the JavaScript community adopted.  I'm not *totally* against it, but we have a lot of tags that are specific to products/libraries that don't need that disambiguation (because the tag wiki is clear).  Are you seeing that `knockout` is being inappropriately applied?  If so, then it's a case for the ".js" but I'd rather go with "knockout" (and "knockout-2.0" or something similar for version-specific).

Comment: No, all "knockout" questions relate to that JS library. I like "knockout-2.0" as well.

Comment: Alright, give me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments, I've done the following:

- [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) has been merged with [knockout](/questions/tagged/knockout)
- The tag wikie for [knockout](/questions/tagged/knockout) has been updated with the content from the old [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs)
- [knockoutjs2](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs2) as been merged with [knockout-2.0](/questions/tagged/knockout-2.0)
- The [knockoutjs-mapping-plugin](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs-mapping-plugin) tag was merged with [knockout-mapping-plugin](/questions/tagged/knockout-mapping-plugin)

I also recommend that we do this with other libraries with "js" in them (unless it's specifically required to disambiguate or specifically part of the name, such as [processing.js](/questions/tagged/processing.js)).

After all, we don't have "jQueryjs". "scriptaliciouisjs", "html-agility-pack-.net", etc.  There's no reason to use it here.

Comment: Ugly solution... If some JavaScript tags need `.js`, then it's better to give them all `.js` than only some.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi If it was actually called "knockout.js", then we'd name it that, [but it's not](http://knockoutjs.com/); it's the name of the *site*, but we don't name things after the sites they are on, but what they're *actually* named.

Comment: Hmm, true.  Still, it doesn't look quite right to me...