# More tag synonyms for Knockout

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

As a followup to [last year's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131779/tag-synonym-for-knockoutjs) about synonyms for [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js), it looks like there are now two more:

- [knockout-mvvm](/questions/tagged/knockout-mvvm)
- <strike>[knockout-mvc](/questions/tagged/knockout-mvc)</strike> **EDIT** This one is not actually the same, it just has a misleading tag wiki that only discusses the JavaScript part of the library without the ASP.NET part.  I have suggested an update for it to clarify.

Both of them are still pretty small (33 questions and 5 questions respectively, as of the time of this writing), but they look like they should be combined, or have all the questions retagged and then the tags removed.

---

As an aside, I'm also not sure if there is utility in having a [knockout-2.0](/questions/tagged/knockout-2.0) tag separate from [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js), without a corresponding [knockout-1.0](/questions/tagged/knockout-1.0) tag.  It seems like most of the questions posted in the [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js) are about version 2 but it seems most are not tagged as such.

Comment: The reason I would be against removing [tag:knockout-2.0] is that there could potentially be a knockout-3.0.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I agrre with you ... but that's still only useful if the not all of the questions are just tagged plain 'knockout'.  Right now, it looks like people aren't using the numbered tag.

Comment: Then we should probably kill the `knockout.js` tag and replace it with the versioned tags.

Comment: Notice that [tag:knockout-mvc] is not a synonym of [tag:knockout.js].

Comment: @kiamlaluno - You're right. What confused me into thinking they are the same was the tag wiki, which says nothing at all about Knockout MVC, only about Knockoutjs.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It looks like a lot of other people were also confused by it - looking at questions tagged [tag:knockout-mvc], there are a whole lot of questions that are regular Knockout questions, not at all applicable to Knockout MVC.